# How to allow registration only from a certain location?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I'm currently working on a Multivendor eCommerce based on Woocommerce (and Multivendor plugin like: Dokan/WP Marketplace/WP Vendor).

I need to allow vendor registration just from a country in the world and exclude it from any other.

Currently, I haven't even been able to understend where to look for: I just need to know where I should be watching out to gain a solution, and I'll be finding the code by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The googles suggested several ways to do this, either with PHP or jQuery.

Here's one article I found to get you started: http://tutorialzine.com/2016/06/quick-tip-detecting-your-location-with-javascript/

Plus there is this Stackoverflow answer that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636671/how-to-setup-the-functionality-to-get-user-location-in-browser

"Geolocation" is a good search term to use.

You'll need to customize you registration form to enable this, but perhaps these links will help.

Good luck.